# How does Infragistics determine what features a browser supports?

Tags: browser, infragistics, feature-detection

With Chrome 100 on the horizon, this has become a concern for us. How does Infragistics determine what features a browser supports?

1. Do they query the user agent string, and query the browser name?
2. Do they query the user agent string and query the browser name *and* version?
3. Do they use feature detection?
4. Do they use both (2) and (3)?
5. Do they do something else entirely?

If they are using 2 or 4, this could present a problem for us, as we rely quite heavily on the Infragistics components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еxcept IE, the browser version is not taken into account into the [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/) product implementation. Having this in mind I do not expect any issues with the Chrome v100 release. In addition, we are currently testing our products in order to be sure there is no issue. You could also test whether everything works as expected on your side using the exposed force-major-version-to-100 flag. More about it could be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/force-major-version-to-100/).

Also, what I could say is that where it is possible we are using feature detection, however, in some scenarios, it is necessary to use user-agent strings. However, as I previously mentioned, we do not expect any issues with Chrom v100.